# Trying to make sure I have this right: Properties of Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Can somebody tell me if this is correct? Let's say we are working with the set A = {a, b, c, d} and the relation R comes from A.

1. Reflexive: the relation is reflexive if and only if **all** of (a, a), (b, b), (c, c) and (d, d) are present. If at least one of them is missing, it is not reflexive.
2. Symmetric: the relation is symmetric if and only if **all** ordered pairs present within the relation have a symmetrically matching ordered pair present as well. For example, {(a, b), (b, a)} is symmetric (even though c and d are never used) but {(a, b), (b, a), (a, c)} is not symmetric.
3. Antisymmetric: the relation is symmetric if and only if **no symmetry exists.** The exception to this rule is in the case of ordered pairs such as (a, a) and (b, b), etc. For example, {(a, b), (a, c)} is antisymmetric because no symmetry exists, but {(a, a), (b, b), (c, c)} is **both symmetric and antisymmetric.**
4. Transitive: the relation is transitive if and only if **all** possibilities for transitivity exist for every ordered pair that is present in the relation. For example, {(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)} is transitive, but {(a, b), (b, c), (a, c), (c, b), (b, d)} is not because (c, b) and (b, d) exist, but not (c, d).

Do I understand these rules correctly? Thank you for any clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d express a few things a bit differently, but the substance is fine. (For instance, I wouldn’t say that an ordered pair **exists**, but rather that it’s **in the relation**.)